# Terser Plugin doesnt run with Vue CLI 5 on vue build

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-5, terser-webpack-plugin

I am trying to create a production build with the following configureWebpack but Terser doesnt run during build.

Code is not minimized or uglified.  Ialso tried `hidden-source-map`

Using `"terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3"` with @vue/cli@5.0.7

isProd is correctly set to true.

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/',
    devServer: {
        host: 'staging-beta.myDomain.com',
        port: 9000,
        allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
    transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        // reducted code
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
        optimization: {
            minimize: isProd,
            minimizer: isProd
                ? [
                      new TerserPlugin({
                          minify: TerserPlugin.uglifyJsMinify,
                          terserOptions: {
                              compress: {
                                  drop_console: true,
                              },
                              output: {
                                  comments: false,
                              },
                          },
                      }),
                  ]
                : [],
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct setup is:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
    terser: {
        minify: 'uglifyJs',
        terserOptions: {
            compress: {
                drop_console: true,
            },
        },
    },
})
```

You also need to `npm install uglify-js`

`comments` under output is deprecated.

Comment: how to config `cache:true, sourceMap:false, parallel:true`?